# prove a function $f(x,y) = \max(x,y)$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider the function $f : R^2 →R$ given by $f(x,y) = \max(x,y)$. (That is, $f(x,y)$ is the larger of $x$ and $y$, so $f(−3,2) = 2$, $f(1,4) = 4$, and $f(−3,−2) = −2$.) (assume that $R^2$ has sup metric)

prove that $f$ is continuous.

I got $d(x,y)-d(p,q) = \max \{|x-p|,|y-q|\} $  and $d(f(x,y)-f(p,q)) = \max(x,y)-\max(p,q)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may also proceed in the same spirit as your last calculations:
$$ x = x'+(x-x') \leq \max\{x',y'\} + \max\{|x-x'|,|y-y'|\} $$
which by symmetry in $x,y$ implies
$$ \max\{x,y\} \leq  \max\{x',y'\} + \max\{|x-x'|,|y-y'|\} $$
and then by symmetry in $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$:
$$ |f(x,y)-f(x',y')|= |\max\{x,y\}- \max\{x',y'\}| \leq  \max\{|x-x'|,|y-y'|\},$$
showing that $f$ is $1$-Lipschitz continuous. Note that
you may adapt this proof to any dimension: $f(x_1,...,x_n)=\max\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ is also $1$-Lipschitz with respect to sup norm in ${\Bbb R}^n$.

Comment: that's exactly what i want. thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: $\max\{x,y\} = \dfrac{x + y + |x - y|}{2}$

Comment: i have no idea how does this work

Comment: @user378456 Adding $\frac{x+y}2$ and $\frac{|x-y|}2$ means that you start at the midpoint of the interval with $x,y$ as endpoints, and move to the right a distance equal to half the length of the interval. That takes you to the right-hand endpoint, which is the maximum of $x$ and $y.$ Now use the fact that addition, subtraction, absolute value, and division are continuous.

Comment: $x+y = \max\{x,y\} + \min\{x,y\}$ and $|x-y| = \max\{x,y\} - \min\{x,y\}$. add these up and you get $x+y+|x-y| = 2\max\{x,y\}$.

Comment: not just to show,i want to prove $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite late, but I'll provide the ideas in a more concrete manner.

that is $$max\{x,y\}=\frac{x+y+|x-y|}{2}$$

First, If we rewrite the given function like that, we can use the definition of uniformly continuity and the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument to prove it.

here is proof :

$\forall$ ($x$,$y$),($s$,$t$) $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^{2}$,

take $$\delta := \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

So If $$||(x,y)-(s,t)||<\delta$$ then

\begin{align}
|f(x,y)-f(s,t)| & = |\frac{x+y+|x-y|}{2}-\frac{s+t+|s-t|}{2}|\\
& = |\frac{x-s}{2}+\frac{y-t}{2}+\frac{|x-y|-|s-t|}{2}| \\
& \leq |\frac{x-s+y-t}{2}| + |\frac{|x-y|-|s-t|}{2}| &\text{triangle inequality} \\
& \leq \frac{1}{2}(|x-s|+|y-t|) + \frac{1}{2}(||x-y|-|s-t||) &\text{triangle inequality}\\
& \leq \frac{1}{2}(|x-s|+|y-t|) + \frac{1}{2}(|x-y-s+t|) & \text{triangle inequality for $||a|-|b|| \leq |a-b|$}\\
& \leq \frac{1}{2}(|x-s|+|y-t|) + \frac{1}{2}(|x-s|+|t-y|)\\
& = |x-s|+|y-t|
\end{align}

Since
\begin{align}
|x-s|=\sqrt{(x-s)^{2}} &\leq \sqrt{(x-s)^{2}+(y-t)^{2}}=||(x,y)-(s,t)||<\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2} &\text{and}\\
|y-t|=\sqrt{(y-t)^{2}} &\leq \sqrt{(x-s)^{2}+(y-t)^{2}}=||(x,y)-(s,t)||<\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{align}

thus we have
$$|x-s|+|y-t| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$

Therefore
for $\delta:=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

$||(x,y)-(s,t)||<\delta$ $\implies$ $|f(x,y)-f(s,t)|<\epsilon$.

i.e. because $(x, y)$ and $(s, t)$ are arbitrary real numbers. $f$ is uniformly continuity